# Requests to API from LocalHost NodeJS/Express app fail, but work in PostMan?

Tags: node.js, express, postman

Here is the code I am using now and plan to have become middleware after I can request back the token from their API for requests.

```
exports.requestToken = function (req, res) {
  const connectionInfo = {
    params: {
      whitelabel_id: crowdContentAuth.api_username,
      whitelabel_key: crowdContentAuth.api_password,
      client_id: crowdContentAuth.client_id,
      client_key: crowdContentAuth.client_key,
    },
  };
  const options = {
    hostname: "api.crowdcontent.com/?request=" + JSON.stringify(connectionInfo),
    port: 443,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

When I request from my application I see the following in the console:

```
0|Server |   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
0|Server |   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
0|Server |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
0|Server |   hostname: 'api.crowdcontent.com/?request={"params":{"whitelabel_id":"redacted","whitelabel_key":"redacted","client_id":"redacted","client_key":"redacted"}}'
```

I am redacting things in the response obviously because it's not-public data, but it's there. The [CrowdContent API](https://developers.crowdcontent.com/documentation) is also a bit older and not exactly how you would typically expect a POST based API to work since the data should be passed in the body of the request and not via the URL.

The API states to use `https://DOMAIN/request=` however after testing in PostMan it appears to be `https://api.crowdcontent.com/?request={stringifiedObjectOfDetails` - When I send a request this way through PostMan I do get a successful response with a token.

```
{"message":"Token is already created. Add the token to your API call are you are good to go.","token":"5713a4d4100b2redacting41e76b4efef0","last_access":"blah"}
```

Is this something I am doing wrong with my request or is this possibly CloudFlare getting involved with the request since it's coming from my localhost/ip?

Clueless at this point to figure out what's causing it.

All other APIs and Post requests in my app are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should you other packages like axios, node-fetch than using http built-in module instead.

Comment: Why so? They all run off the http module do they not?

Comment: @Dadsquatch i really don't know why but i used to use http built-in module to fetch data but sometimes it will clearly output data as you expect but sometimes no. So i've changed to use axios and i see it always work as i expect so maybe you should use it as default

Comment: Just wanted to say I did move over to Axios and the issue resolved. Going to mark this as correct and the answer although it should work both ways, but looks like Axios likely wraps in some things the native HTTP module doesn't on it's POST requests that a API might want, but not disclose. Thanks by the way!